# Django transaction roll back while updating record

Tags: python, django, csv, transactions

I have CSV file which updates records in bulk.

CSV format:

```
id  amount
4   100
5   200
6   five   --> error
7   400
```

I want to roll back to the previous state of data if there is an error in CSV data.

Like in above CSV **id 6** has a string and my column in the database is an integer so it will throw an exception.

views.py

```
from django.db import transaction
lines = csv.reader(my_csv.csv)
for line in lines:
    try:
       MyModel.objects.filter(id=line[0]).update(amount=line[1])
    except:
      transaction.rollback()
      break
```

**exception**

```
("'%(value)s' value must be a decimal number.", 'invalid', {'value': 'five'})
[]
```

We my code goes in exception for **id 6** new data is getting update .

Comment: Can you post exact traceback?

Comment: @NafeesAnwar see the update

Comment: Your model has amount as `DecimalField` and you are providing string value to it (`five`).

Comment: yes, I know but whenever this kind of error occurs I need to do roll back to the previous state.

Comment: Have you tried [transaction.atomic()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.atomic)?

Comment: @NafeesAnwar yes I have tried this but not working.

Comment: I would suggest [bulk_update()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-update). It will perform update for all objects in a single query which will fail or pass for all objects.

Answer (score 1):

updated your code :

using the with transaction.atomic(), will consider all the db commits as one transaction and in case of a exception or error it will rollback/un-save every entry it made

```
from django.db import transaction
    lines = csv.reader(my_csv.csv)
try:
    with transaction.atomic():      
    for line in lines:
           MyModel.objects.filter(id=line[0]).update(amount=line[1])
except:
transaction.rollback()
break
```

I'd prefer you to use a function to check and verify data before entering in db as it is better instead of a rollback approach